# Toggle paragraph using link from another paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I have similar code like this. Except for the fact that my JS file is external. The function myFunction() is called in the beginning of that file, like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  myFunction()
})
```

But, it's not working - it's not showing the text from the second paragraph, when clicked on the word HERE from the first paragraph. I assume that maybe I should call the function somehow else. Any given ideas would be really helpful. Thanks.

P.S. Also, when clicked, the window should scroll to the newly opened paragraph.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myCollapsible2")
  
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
p{
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 30px;
}
.bs-example{
 margin: 20px;
}
.link-color {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js">.</script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bs-example">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myCollapsible" value="Toggle Button">
            <div id="myCollapsible" class="collapse"><p>This is a simple example of expanding and collapsing individual element via data attribute. <br>Click on the <b>Toggle Button</b> button to see the effect. If you click <a onclick="myFunction()" class="link-color" href="#">here</a>, you should see the other paragraph. </p></div>
            <div id="myCollapsible2" class="collapse"><p>This is a simple example</p></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why it's not working? What you want to accomplish? You want that the text be visible when you load? Also what you mean by "should lead to the newly opened paragraph"? The window should scroll to it?

Comment: Hi @ariel, yes, the window should scroll to it. And the text should be visible when clicking on HERE (HERE is in the first paragraph and when clicking on it, the second paragraph should open and the window should scroll to it). Currently on my project it's not showing the text from the second paragraph.

Comment: updated my answer with the scrolling part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using bootstrap with popper, your function is unnecessary, just set the values according to the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/). To scroll to the element, use the [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method. I had to wrap it around a setTimeout, because the default method was executing afterwards, so when I called scroll the element wasn't visible yet.

```js
function scrollTo2() {
  var el = document.getElementById('myCollapsible2');
  window.setTimeout(() => el.scrollIntoView(), 0);
}
```

```css
p {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 30px;
}

.bs-example {
  margin: 20px;
}

.link-color {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="bs-example">
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-target="#myCollapsible" value="Toggle Button">
  <div id="myCollapsible" class="collapse show">
    <p>This is a simple example of expanding and collapsing individual element 
      via data attribute.<br>Click on the <b>Toggle Button</b> 
      button to see the effect. 
      If you click <a onclick="scrollTo2()" data-toggle="collapse" 
      data-target="#myCollapsible2" class="link-color" href="#">here</a>,
      you should see the other paragraph. </p>
    <div id="myCollapsible2" class="collapse">
      <p>This is a simple example</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```